# check if user available before submitting form in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, forms, api, react-hooks, formik

i'm using **formik** and in my Register form i have on textfield username , i want to check if the username available or not before submitting the form so i make one function onhandle change event as :

```
 <FormControl >
            <TextField 
              name="userName"
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              value={values.userName}
              onChange={(e)=>{handleChange(e);checkAvailabilty(e)}}
              error={touched.userName && Boolean(errors.userName) }
              helperText={touched.userName && errors.userName }
           />
            <FormHelperText error>
            {userError ? userError  : null}
            </FormHelperText>

</FormControl>
```

and the function is :

```
const checkAvailabilty = async(e) =>{
  try{
  let response = await axios.get(`${state.baseUrl}users/is_available/${e.target.value}`)
    if(response.status.code === 200)
    {setUserError(false)}
  }
  catch(error){
    if(error.response.status=== 409)
    {setUserError("available")}
  }
}
```

so whenever any user exist it will set user error with available

but the problem is setuserError is not set accordingly on http code **200** it will not set with false once it set with available it keep set available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation yet to comment unfortunately, but there were a few things I wanted to ask:

- Does your `state.baseUrl` end with a `/`?
- Wouldn't it be better to respond with a `404` Not found instead of `409`?

I also believe you only need to check `response.status` and not `response.status.code` to check the response code.

Comment: yes it solved by using **response.status**